# Create user and assign permission to user in LocalDB in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localdb

Can someone please tell me how I can create a user with a password and grant it owner permission to a database that I created in LocalDB in Visual Studio.

It creates a user with no login but I need to create one with a password and owner rights to a database.

Comment: Can you provide some more context about what you are doing, and why you need this?  Maybe localdb isn't the right choice?

Comment: Nothing much just testing a simple application..DOn't have sql installed so was playing around with localDB..I pretty much use the UI to create and assign permission since not a database person but stuck here in LocalDB

Comment: I'm not following - you can just attach the localdb and use it - it's not really suitable for multiple users accessing it simultaneously.  Maybe this will help: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/localdb-automatic-instance-with-specific-data-file/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- Open **SQL Server Object Explorer** (e.g. from the Visual Studio *View* menu)
- Expand your localdb instance in the tree (e.g. *(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB*)
- Right click your database and select *New Query...*
- Execute the following sql:

...

```
CREATE LOGIN [SomeUser] WITH PASSWORD = 'topsecret';
CREATE USER [SomeUser] FOR LOGIN [SomeUser];
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'SomeUser'
```

Comment: It helped. Thanks! Also because i didn't first run it under ''master" db. Needed to also execute the following command: `EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'SomeUser', @rolename = N'dbcreator'
GO`

Comment: But it is still possible to connect DB without password. Could it be disabled?