# Cannot open database msqllocaldb

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, webmatrix, localdb

I had mssqllocaldb database in my asp.net mvc project it was working fine. I just imported mdf file from before. It uses windows authentication and because i changed windows it's another user. It gives me this error.

"Cannot open database \"[mycontext]\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user '[mycurrentuser]'."

Can i do something about it. That database would work without building it again.

[image: problem]

Answer (score 0):

My observation would like to point to few things to help you narrow down toward solution.

- It would be more helpful to narrow down the issue if you could post some code!
- As you mentioned, you are using windows authentication, the application would run under the ASP.NET account. Try granting that windows user permission to access the database and check again running the application.
- Try granting the user permission like:

  exec sp_grantlogin 'MachineName\ASPNET'
- Also try going through link - it may provide additional direction in your issue.
  [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/775607/how-to-fix-localdb-requested-login-failed)

Comment: I'm using simple membership authentication

Comment: I tried sp_grantlogin it say that it completes successfully but when i start app it's the same problem

Comment: I used - exec sp_grantlogin 'MachineName\myname' not with aspnet

Comment: just making sure that you used your own machine name. For example, my machine name is WinSystem04\yourusername. (here 'yourusername' meaning the user which is stored in your membership database.

Comment: I used like that. It even says that it succeded

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create sql user and use the user to login instead

how to do it can be found here

[Create user and assign permission to user in LocalDB in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597979/create-user-and-assign-permission-to-user-in-localdb-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I tried this, but it gave me another error - User guest does not have permission to run DBCC checkprimaryfile

Comment: you have to give full permission to the windows user on the mdf file as well

Comment: I did that and it's the same thing