# Cannot open database "name" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, localdb

I have deployed my web app on a server and I am trying to connect to a database on localdb. I am getting this error.

```
Cannot open database "hands.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.
```

I have created 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' login on the SQL server and given it access to all possible roles under user mapping.

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#D3DF8A08\tsql\query;Initial Catalog=hands.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have looked at similar requests and followed the advice with no luck. I have tried to change

```
"integrated security" to User ID=domain\administrator;pwd=password"
```

But still no luck.

Can someone help me with getting this working please?

Comment: for localdb you should put the full path in the connection string. For easy testing create a text file with extension .UDL and doubleclick it from windows explorer

Comment: Please update your question with the code you used to create USER

Comment: @GuidoG Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: Your problem is that you created only LOGIN, you did not create USER

Comment: @sepupic Do you mean the user : 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' I added it in SQL server management studio

Comment: You added a login, I ask you if you created a USER, but you didn't. that's why you get this error. Your login is not mapped to this database

Comment: Thanks @sepupic how do I create the user?

Comment: Se here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597979/create-user-and-assign-permission-to-user-in-localdb-in-visual-studio

Comment: CREATE LOGIN [SomeUser] WITH PASSWORD = 'topsecret'; Should the SomeUser be APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool in my case

Comment: >>>CREATE LOGIN<< is creating LOGIN. And you need to create USER. Don't you see CREATE USER command in the link above?

Comment: That was just an example, I will run all the commands from your link. just wanted to double check the user name to use.

Comment: Ok so I ran the commands in the link for user "HSLog" still get the same error. I was unable to have IIS APPPOOL before the username because sql complained about it containing illegal characters in the name.  Cannot open database "hands.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'HSLog'.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' doesn't have permission to access hands.mdf directory.

Comment: Any idea how I check that?

Comment: [Application Pool Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) This link can help you

Answer (score 0):

All sorted problem was very simple at the end.

My original connection string was connecting to a local file i.e.

```
AttachDbFilename=hands.mdf
```

So when I changed to a attached SQL file

```
Initial Catalog=hands     I should have removed (.mdf)
```